# Xcopy directory pattern matching

Tags: batch-file, pattern-matching, xcopy

I need to copy source file to destination folder using bat file.

I have created this:

```
@echo off

set source="D:\Folder1\file.dll"
set destination="D:\Test\TestCopy*\Test\"
xcopy /s /y %source%  %destination%
pause
```

The destination path I have is `TestCopy.2.5.3.6`. This numbers can change. So specifying `TestCopy*` is not working. Specifying `TestCopy.*.*.*.*` also not working.

How can I solve this?

Comment: Wildcards like `*` and `?` can only be used in the last element of a path; you could work around your issue using a [`for /D` loop](http://ss64.com/nt/for_d.html) like this: `for /D %%D in ("D:\Test\TestCopy.*.*.*.*") do mkdir "%%~D\Test" & copy /Y "D:\Folder1\file.dll" "%%~D\Test\"`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That is not the way `xcopy` is used; it cannot copy directory structures/files to multiple folders, e.g. copy file `random.ext` to `C:\folder1\test`, `C:\folder2\test`, etc.

Also, no need to use `xcopy` to copy *files*. Just use `copy` instead.

To achieve this, use:

```bat
@echo off

pushd "D:\Test"
set source="D:\Folder1\file.dll"

for /F "delims= eol=" %%A IN ('dir /B /AD "D:\Test\TestCopy*"') do (
    copy %source% "%%~fA\Test\"
)
popd
```

Or, better one-line `for /F`:

```bat
@echo off

pushd "D:\Test"
set source="D:\Folder1\file.dll"

for /F "delims= eol=" %%A IN ('dir /B /AD "D:\Test\TestCopy*"') do copy %source% "%%~fA\Test\"
popd
```

Answer (score 3):

This is for the situation when you have multiple `TestCopy*` subfolders:

```
::It's better to comment out @echo off when you are testing the batch file
::@echo off
::Moved the open quote's position, so the source variable won't have quotes inside.
set "source=D:\Folder1\file.dll"
for /F "delims=" %%i IN ('dir /ad /b "D:\Test\TestCopy*"') do call :fcopy "%%i"
::Comment or remove pause when it's okay.
pause
goto :eof

:fcopy
if not exist "D:\Test\%1\Test\" goto :eof
xcopy "%source%" "D:\Test\%1\Test\"
```

Used a sub procedure `:fcopy`, pass each `TestCopy*` subfolder name to it.
All `::` starting lines are comment lines. They are not executed.

I think it's a good habit to quote every path variable when used, but don't include the quotes themselves in the variable -- that's why I moved the quote in the `set source` line.